# Query a single table as master and detail and sort result where master row will be on top of each detail

Tags: mysql, sql, row

can this be done? please help me.

I tried union, only it is not sorted like the way i want it - master row on top of detail row. Thank you..

```
SELECT 
mover.v_id, 
mover.v_registration, 
mover.attached_with       
from ops_vehicle mover
LEFT JOIN v_l_type ON (mover.type = v_l_type.idv_type)
where v_l_type.trailer = FALSE       
union all
SELECT 
trailer.v_id, 
trailer.v_registration, 
trailer.attached_with
from ops_vehicle trailer
LEFT JOIN v_l_type ON (trailer.type = v_l_type.idv_type)
where v_l_type.trailer = TRUE
```

result: 
[query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUhyB.png)

The result i want is something like this:

```
v_id      v_registration      attached_with
-------------------------------------------
1         ABC 123             4
4         T/B 123
2         CBA 876             5
5         T/B 763
3         OPQ 631
```

The result row with v_id=4 should be under the v_id=1 because attached_with is 4.

Comment: Please, describe the problem in question, not only in title

Comment: I presume you want to do a JOIN. However, you should describe your problem further in order for people to be sure on what you want to do.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Going to edit it.

Comment: Please add an example of expected outcome.

Comment: Just added it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
order by coalesce(attached_with, v_id),
         (attached_with is not null) desc,
         v_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but why in the first result (v_id=3), the detail is on top of the master, this is the result: https://imgur.com/a/O1YUVdf

Comment: @ageep . . . One more key may be needed in the `order by`.  I just modified it.